Catching Android Keyevent for Shift as keycode or metaState from USB Barcode Scanner in HID mode
I have a Android 11 Zebra device with a Barcode Scanner in HID mode.
The keyevents are send to the app and I see the pressed keys. Unfortunately I have a problem when uppercase letters are used.
Then I get a "shift" problem: e.g. Barcode ABCDE1234 is going to be ABcdE!234
Locking at the Keyevents I'll see that for uppercase A the keycode is set after the letter:
29 KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_A, scanCode=0, metaState=META_SHIFT_ON|META_SHIFT_LEFT_ON, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=16823473, downTime=16823473, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
59 KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=16823473, downTime=16823473, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
Also additionally the metaState of the Key is set, I guess saying that is an uppercase A. But when the metaState is already set up why is then a second Keyevent for shift?
I'm not sure how to handle barcodes that contain lowercase,uppercase and numbers. This is my code so far: for every scanned letter/numer the onKeyUp is triggered.
var myBarcodeString = ""
var shift = false

public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            char unicodeChar = (char) event.getUnicodeChar();
            //shift key is pressed
            if (keyCode == 59) {
                shift = true;
            }
            //numbers and letters
            if (keyCode >= 29 && keyCode <= 54 ||keyCode >= 7 && keyCode <= 10) {
                if (shift) {
                    myBarcodeString += Character.toUpperCase(unicodeChar);
                    shift = false;
                } else {
                    myBarcodeString += unicodeChar;

            }else {
                // key is scanned that is not a numer or letter or 
                return true;
            }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}

How can I adjust the code to create a string out of the scanned barcode with mix of uppercase, lowercase letters and numbers?
